# Choosing a subset of V that exceeds half its sum.

Tags: linear-algebra, natural-numbers

Say I had s vectors in $R^4$ whose entries were in the set of non-negative integers. Let $\bar{v}$ be the average of these vectors. How can you prove that there exists a subset of $\frac{s}{2} + 2$ of these vectors such that their sum is greater than $\frac{s}{2}\times \bar{v}$ in all four dimensions? I was able to prove this in the case of R^2 but my approach didn't generalize to higher dimensions, could anyone give me an idea of how to get started?

Sorry in advance English is my second language

Comment: Do you consider zero a natural number?

Comment: My bad! I don't but the question should consider 0, yes. Thanks!